# Making SSH connection to Centos 6.5 VM takes ages

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, connection, centos-6

I installed Centos 6.5 in a Virtual Box VM. Everything works smooth, except for SSH logins. It takes ages for the command prompt to display.

With some verbosity added:

```
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /Users/verhage/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f82a2600350),
debug2: key: /Users/verhage/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
```

Of course I googled and this seems to have to do with a hanging reverse DNS lookup right? I edited my /etc/ssh/ssh_config and it looks like this:

```
Host *
    UseDNS no
    GSSAPIAuthentication no
# If this option is set to yes then remote X11 clients will have full access
# to the original X11 display. As virtually no X11 client supports the untrusted
# mode correctly we set this to yes.
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
# Send locale-related environment variables
    SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
    SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
    SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
    SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

As you can see, both UseDNS and GSSAPIAuthentication are set to no. As setting these parameters to no are the only suggestions I can find online, what could be my problem?

Comment: Ok, this was very, very stupid. I have been editing the client configuration file...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Upon searching I got the solution [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/58625):

Add the following line to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
options single-request-reopen
```